# In GCP, How do I give a role the permission to access a secret?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-secret-manager

I am trying to access a secret stored in secret manager, following [this](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#secretmanager-create-secret-python).
It says:

> Accessing a secret version requires the Secret Manager Secret
> Accessor role (roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor) on the
> secret, project, folder, or organization.  IAM roles can't be
> granted on a secret version.

So, how do I apply the  `Secret Manager Secret Accessor role` to the secret?

Comment: You don't apply the role to the secret but to the account trying to access it

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to grant the role for the user or service account at the most restrictive level, which in this case should be the secret itself. This can be done as follows:

```
gcloud secrets add-iam-policy-binding my_secret \
  --member='serviceAccount:my_service_account@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com' \
  --project=my_project \
  --role='roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor'
```

Comment: The question referring access to the secret , it would be probably done by a service account

Answer (score -1):

The quote refers to granting the user who wants to access the secret, the role of `secretmanager.secretAccessor`.

To grant a role:

> 1. In the Google Cloud console, go to the IAM page.
> 2. Select a project, folder, or organization.
> 3. Select a principal to grant a role to:
>
> To grant a role to a principal who already has other roles on the
> resource, find the row containing the principal's email address, click
> edit Edit principal in that row, and click add Add another role.
>
> To grant a role to a Google-managed service account, select the
> Include Google-provided role grants checkbox to see its email address.
>
> Note: You cannot edit inherited roles when managing access to a
> resource. To edit inherited roles, go to the resource where the role
> was granted. To grant a role to a principal who does not already have
> other roles on the resource, click person_add Add, then enter the
> principal's email address.
>
> 4. Select a role to grant from the drop-down list. For best security
>    practices, choose a role that includes only the permissions that
>    your principal needs.
> 5. Optional: Add a condition to the role.
> 6. Click Save. The principal is granted the role on the resource.

In this [page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access), you will find more information about Manage access to projects, folders, and organizations

Comment: This grants the role for ALL secrets in the project, folder or organization, which is not what was requested in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to add a role to a `Service Account` and not for the `secret` object

The relevant operation of accessing a secret will be done by a Entity(User or Service Account) with permissions granted by the relevant role

You can add the relevant role to the relevant service account with one line as following:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding  <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> --member='serviceAccount:99999999@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor'
```

Comment: This grants the role for ALL secrets in the project, which is not what was requested in the question.